# ElasticBeanstalk Console for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does Amazon's AWS Elastic Beanstalk service provide a console to interact with the application?

When using Rails locally and through Heroku, you have the opportunity to interact with the environment from the command line, but I can't find any documentation on AWS that talks about any such CLI for the app while hosted on Beanstalk.

Locally you would use `rails console` and through Heroku you would use `heroku run console`, but I can't figure out how to do this on AWS.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you give an example of interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - What I was looking to do is called 'SSH'. I didn't know that term, but now I get it.

For someone who's always been on Heroku, I've never known that term.